# Is it possible to span an entry over multiple pages with Structure?

Tags: channel-entries, structure

I would like to have a Structure managed page span the content of that entry over multiple pages using the method in the [EE Docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/pagination_spanning.html).

My code:

```
 {exp:channel:entries channel="articles" paginate_type="field" paginate="bottom" limit="1" }
        <h1>{title}</h1>         
        {multi_field="page1|page2|page3|page4|page5"}

        {paginate}
        Page {current_page} of {total_pages} | {pagination_links}
        {/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The first page shows the content from {page1} however each addition page is empty.

I have also tried adding dynamic="no" & url_title="{segment_2}" to the exp:channel:entries tag with the same results.

Are there any other options that I might be missing or is this just not possible?

Thank you

Comment: This needs to be solved completely manually instead of "Spanning a Channel Entry Across Multiple Pages". Freebie could be helpful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each entry is attached to a single URL, but with something like Freebie you possibly could. You could have an initial channel tag on the main page wrapped in conditionals. This channel tag would have the certain fields you want to show. Then if you appended a random segment on the end that Freebie is ignoring, you could have another channel tag showing the remaining ones.